# Use count with condition in SQL

Tags: sql

Write a query to display the team names and the number of wins of the teams in the tournament. In case if any of the teams hasn't won any of the games, display the win_count as 0. Give an alias name to the number of wins as 'win_count'. Display the records sorted in ascending order based on team name.

I tried this query but it's not working

```
select 
    t.name, count(case when o.status='WIN' then true else '0') as win_count   
from 
    team t 
inner join 
    outcome o on t.id = o.winner_team_id
group by 
    t.name
order by 
    t.name asc
```

Sample data:

**TEAM**:

```
    ID  NAME    
    -----------------
    1   BENGAL  
    2   BENGALURU   
    3   DELHI   
    4   JAIPUR
    5   PATNA   
    6   PUNE    
    7   PUNJAB  
    8   KOLKATA
```

**OUTCOME**:

```
    ID  STATUS  WINNER_TEAM_ID  
    ---------------------------
    1   WIN     2
    2   WIN     4
    3   WIN     5
    4   WIN     7
    5   CANCELLED   NULL
    6   WIN     4
    7   WIN     8
    8   WIN     7   
    9   WIN     8
    10  WIN     7
    11  WIN     2
    12  WIN     1   
    13  WIN     4
    14  WIN     2
    15  WIN     5
    16  WIN     5   
    17  WIN     8   
    18  WIN     7   
    19  WIN     4   
    20  WIN     3
    21  WIN     4   
    22  WIN     2
```

Comment: Pick a DBMS, not three.

Comment: HINT : `group by`

Comment: sum(case when o.Status='WIN' then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: "but its not working" is not a problem description. Do you get an error? If so, what's the error message? `then true else '0'` you shouldn't (can't) mix datatypes in a `case` expression.

Comment: i have to pass the test case and its showing wrong

Comment: You shouldn't use `COUNT()` for this.  Try using `SUM(CASE WHEN O.Status = 'Win' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: not working with sum.... i had to count the winning team numbers

Comment: Siyual's solution should work, what's your issue with it?

Comment: Perhaps you should supply the desired results

Comment: i dont have any desired result... the test case will pass automatically if it was right

Comment: can we use condition in using where condition

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily done with a group by.

```
SELECT t.Name, COUNT(o.ID) AS WIN_COUNT
FROM Team t
LEFT JOIN Outcome o ON o.Winner_Team_ID = t.ID
GROUP BY t.ID
ORDER BY t.Name;
```

Comment: As per the requirements of OP `LEFT JOIN` is required.

Comment: i tried with left join also but still having problem

Comment: I edited to fill your other requirements. It's not a very good exercise to have someone else do it for your though....